# Is there a way to not use pointer in returning array? (warning: passing argument 1 of 'arrangef' makes pointer from integer without a cast.)

Tags: c

I tried to write 2 subprograms to arrange an array in ascending and descending order, but it gave me this problem with pointers and cast. Is there a way to go around this?

I tried to put all codes into one big program and it works flawlessly.
I tried to cast pointers in the subprograms but it didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void arrangef (int a[]){
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i=0;;i++){
        for (j=1;;j++){
            if (a[i]>a[j]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void arrangeb (int a[]){
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i=0;;i++){
        for (j=1;;j++){
            if (a[i]>a[j]) {}
                else {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int i, n;
    printf("What is the size of your array?\t"); scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("\nInsert element #%d of array\t",i+1); scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);}

    printf("\n");

    arrangef(a[n]);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);}
    printf("\n");

    arrangeb(a[n]);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be 3 lists of number, the original, the ascending arranged and the descending arrange, but the program crashes.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the problem. You are passing `a[n]` when need to pass `a`. Also I don't see how your loops in the functions are supposed to terminate.

Comment: Hello Eugene, may I ask what you meant by passing? And the loop are supposed to run infinitely since i want to make a program that can sort through arrays of all sizes. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Running infinitely doesn't mean that it will work on all sizes. It means that it will keep running and read past the end of the array.

Comment: "passing" refers to the point, where you call a function with some arguments like in `arrangef(a[n]);`. There, you are *passing* `a[n]` to the function, so the value can be used inside.

Comment: Your functions are expected to take an array as argument but you pass it an `int` instead (`a[n]` is an *element* - which is out of bounds, by the way - of `a`). And your loops can't run indefinitely as it will obviously access the arrays out of bounds. and won't terminate.

Comment: You need to learn some basics. Your function expect the pointer but you pass the integer instead. This integer will be used as a nonsense pointer in the infinitive loop.

Comment: Since you say you have a working program (1 function for all), your question seems to be, how to refactor a specific piece of code into a separate function?

Comment: I see. Thank you all. I wonder, is it impossible to design a program that sorts arrays of desired size? Since many said that if I don't establish an upper boundary, I can't stop the program.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Just pass the size to the function.

Comment: @grek40, yes, I just can't seem to factor it. P__J__, you see, our syllabus focuses heavily on the thought process instead of the syntax, so I lack some serious skills. I'm compensating by reading K&R and I'm watching CS50. But I'm not sure if that's enough.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well yes :))))), but I want the user to decide how big the array they want to sort. Should I, instead of using 1 variable, use 2 variables, like: void arranged (int n, int a[n])?

Comment: This would be one of approaches.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I tried, but lo and behold, it still crashed. I used 2 variables to store the size of array and the number of loops and yet...

Comment: Programs crash for different reasons. We can't help you with code we don't see. You can post another question about that one

Comment: Of course. Thank you all so much for helping :)))))

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: Each of the sub functions needs two parameters: 1) a pointer to the first byte of the array and 2) the number of elements in the array.   Note: `a[n]` is the contents of the memory just past the end of the array which does no good.  Suggest: in fuinction: `main()` `arrangef(a, n)` and `arrangef(a, n);`  Note: the name of an array, in C, degrades to the address of the first byte of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass an *array* to a function, just specify the array name<sup>1</sup>:

```
arrangef( a );
...
arrangeb( a );
```

`a[n]` specifies a single element of the array, and it's one past the *last* element in the array, so you're passing an expression of the wrong type (the `arrange*` functions expect `int *`, you're passing `int`) and it's outside the bounds of the array, so the value isn't known.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So when you call

```
arrangef( a );
```

the expression `a` is implicitly converted from "`n`-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the address of `a[0]`, so what `arrangef` actually receives is a pointer value.

In a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a` - all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.

Since all the function receives is the address of the first element of the array, you must also either pass the number of elements as a separate parameter, or one element will have to contain a sentinel value that marks the end of the data (such as the 0 terminator in strings).  In your case, you need to pass the size separately:

```
void arrangef( int *a, size_t n ) // or int a[]
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) // don't loop past the last element in the array
  {
    for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) 
    {
      int tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

`arrangeb` will look the same, just with the different ordering.

`for( i = 0; ; i++ )` will loop "forever" - it will loop past the end of your array and eventually into memory that you don't own, leading to a runtime error.  `i` will also eventually overflow, and the behavior on signed integer overflow isn't well-defined.  Basically, that loop *will* blow up.

---

1. Actually, you would pass any *expression* of array type, which gets converted to a pointer type, but for now we'll just stick with the name.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (j=1;;j++){
```

This line will loop forever and will access `*(a+j)` in `a[i] = a[j]` outside the bounds of `a`.  Similarly with three other loops in your code.  Specify an upper bound:

```
for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
```

You'll need to pass the size of the array to the function too, and call it with `arrangef(a, n);`.  At the moment, you are passing the value one after the end of the array to the function, which is expecting a pointer, not a value.

Comment: Hello alinsoar, I wanted to make a program that can sort through arrays of all sizes, hence I left the upper bound open. Is it something coders frown upon?

Comment: "frown upon"? Non-terminating programs are useless. Programs accessing arrays out of bounds are both incorrect and have undefined behavior (well.. they mostly crash).

Comment: @TrươngQuốcQuân You do not set any terminating condition inside your for-loop, so the for-loop will grow `j` indefinitely.  In the moment when `j>n` the behavior is undefined.  It crashes.  You need to set `for (j=1;j<n;j++)` and pass `n` as parameter to `arrangef `.